# передача одного из свойств структуры по указателю

Tags: c, строки, функции, указатели, struct

Объясните пожалуйста, где моя ошибка?
имеется следующая структура:

```
struct mainStruct {char *name; float numFloat; int numInt;} product;
```

и имеется функция в которая получает на вход указатель на char **getPointer:

```
void Func1(char **getPointer, char *text) {
   printf("\n%s", text);
   scanf("%[^\n\r]", *getPointer);
}
```

и при попытке передать указатель следующим образом:

```
Func1(&product.name, "Enter name: ");
```

У меня пропускается ввод и по итогу свойство name имеет значение NULL

p.s.func1 находится в отдельном файле, при передаче оставшихся свойств во внешние функции все работает корректно ( оставшиейся функции принимают параметры по типу float *getVar и int *getInt соответственно)

Comment: А куда вы читаете? Перед этим "свойство" `name` было как-то инициализировано? Вы же просто читаете по адресу, хранящемуся в `name` — так что никакого изменения самого `name` нет и не должно быть. Надеюсь, память-то вы выделили, `name` при вызове указывает на буфер для чтения? (Думаю, вам ст*о*ит  еще раз перечитать, как именно работает функция `scanf`...)

Comment: А куда вы читаете? - никуда пока что.
Перед этим "свойство" name было как-то инициализировано? - как раз вызываю данную функцию что бы инициализировать
У меня пропускается ввод и по итогу свойство name имеет значение NULL - 
передаю в функцию параметры,  выводится строка "Enter name: ", пропускается получение ввода от пользователя до указанных символов "scanf("$[^\n\r]", *getPointer);" и взываются 2 функция получения ввода для типо float и it.

Comment: При этом если сделать вот так: 
char *str;
Func1(&str, "Enter value: ");
то переменная str будет инициализированна строкой и потом ее можно спокойно вывести. но Почему то при передачи указателя на свойство структуры так не работае...

Comment: после процента нужно добавить букву `m` : `scanf("%m[^\n\r]", *getPointer);`

Comment: .. этот знак даёт повод функции изменить указатель на новую выделенную память

Comment: @AlexGlebe Гм... `%m` - это какое-то нестандартное расширение?..

Comment: @Harry такое написано в `$ man scanf` пишет предупреждение : `<source>:6:10: warning: ISO C does not support the 'm' scanf flag [-Wformat=]` Скорее всего нужно было просто поставить сначала нулевой указатель

Comment: вы же этот указатель передаёте как просто значение, которое невозможно просто так изменить. чтобы указателю на строку изменить значение (*адрес на выделенную память*) нужно давать указатель на переменную типа `char *` *(`char * *`)*. Нестандартное решение это `scanf("%m[^\n\r]", getPointer);` , что будет менять указатель, на который указывает `getPointer`. Или выделить самому память, как уже предложили в ответе.

Answer (score 2):

Надо примерно так

```
void Func1(char **getPointer, char *text)
{
    *getPointer = malloc(200);
    printf("\n%s", text);
    scanf("%199[^\n\r]", *getPointer);
}
```

Т.е. выделить какую-то память через `malloc` - только потом не забыть ее освободить при помощи `free`.

На ваше

> `char *str; Func1(&str, "Enter value: ");` то переменная str будет инициализированна строкой и потом ее можно спокойно вывести

Вы просто не поняли, что это грубая ошибка. `char *str;` - локальная переменная, и вам так *не* повезло, что она, похоже, содержала мусор, указывающий на какую-то разрешенную память, в которую и записалась строка. Типичное неопределенное поведение...

Сами проверьте - сравните значение `str` до и после вызова функции.

Comment: тогда после процента уже поставьте 199 : `scanf("%199[^\n\r]", *getPointer);`

Comment: @AlexGlebe Ну да, логично, спасибо.